# How can I disable the firewall on OS X after forgetting how I set it?

Tags: macos, network, firewall

I have enabled an option on my mac to ask for permission every time I open an network application, But I can't seem to find out how to turn it off.

Where would I disable the below dialog?

[image: dialog]

Comment: Would you like to disable the firewall entirely, or just whitelist that one app?

Answer (score 1):

As the dialog explains, you can turn off the firewall in the Security preferences pane (or Security & Privacy, on newer versions of OS X).